# Can't get button to call inside function and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, function, pygame

I am fairly new to python and pygame and have been struggling with the idea of functions quite a bit - I can't seem to make buttons call to the main function from a sub function. I can make it all work in the main function but that is not what I am trying to do I want to be able to call a button into the main function when it is needed. Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
import sys
import pygame
import button

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Main Page")
icon = pygame.image.load('Sprites/icons8-robber-32.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

start_image = pygame.image.load('Sprites/play.png').convert_alpha()

def buttons(arg1):
     start_button = button.Button(350, 100, start_image, 0.2)
     arg1(start_button)
     return arg1

while running:
    time_delta = clock.tick(60)/1000.0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if start_button.draw(screen):
        print("no")

    pygame.display.update()


buttons(arg1)

pygame.QUIT()
sys.exit()
```

Thank you!

Edit:
including button code

```
import pygame

class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width*scale), int(height*scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True


        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        return action
```

Comment: The phrase "call a button into the main function" doesn't have any clear meaning.  What exactly do you want to have happen when your button gets clicked?

Comment: I am in the same situation as @Samwise : I unfortunatly don't understand what you mean by "call a button into the main function". More than that, I would like to know I don't really see what is your code supposed to do when the button is clicked. I also think that you would need to look at [python's documentation about functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) in order to see what is going worg in your code.

Comment: Sorry that makes sense - I want the button under def buttons() to be drawn in the main loop and not the def buttons() function - I can do it all in the main loop of course but I want to be able to split my functions up for ease of use and finding them.

I will edit the question to include my button code

Comment: Right now what I want the button to do when clicked is just print "no" but that is only because I haven't figured out to get the button to be returned to the main loop from the function (def buttons() )

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're making you button after the main `while True` loop.

Make your button before you start the mainloop and it should be a global variable.
I have modified your code and defined `start_button`. You can create a new button, assign it attributes according to arguments and more. Then you can return the button and store it in a global variable.

```
import sys
import pygame
import button

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Main Page")
icon = pygame.image.load('Sprites/icons8-robber-32.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

start_image = pygame.image.load('Sprites/play.png').convert_alpha()

def create_button(args): #Give your arguments
    button = button.Button(350, 100, start_image, 0.2)
    # Your code...
    return button

start_button = create_button(args)

while running:
    time_delta = clock.tick(60)/1000.0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if start_button.draw(screen):
        print("no")

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.QUIT()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: I could get it to work without a function I'm trying to get it to work with a function because I have a lot more that needs to go in the function than one button - this is just a simplified version. Sorry if this isn't making sense - essentially the function is going to be a second "page" of the program so I want everything that will be on that second page to come out of the function - but still have the program be able to end in the main loop.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually makes sense seeing the way you did it too. I would upvote your answer but I don't have the ability to do that yet. So I hope my thanks is enough!